# Problem showing Newtons Laws are invariant under the Euclidean Group

Tags: group-theory

> I am trying to show that the equations of motions of physics are invariant under the Euclidean group $E_N$ for $N=3$. Therefore we have Newton's Laws as: $$m\frac{d^2 \mathbf{x}(t)}{dt^2}=-GmM\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t) \right \|^3},M\frac{d^2 \mathbf{x}(t)}{dt^2}=-GmM\frac{\mathbf{y}(t)-\mathbf{x}(t)}{\left \|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t) \right \|^3}$$

And so I work out; let new vectors be defined as $\mathbf{x'}(t)=A\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{y'}(t)=A\mathbf{y}(t)+\mathbf{b}$, where $A\in O(3)$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{b}$ a constant vector. Now we see if $\mathbf{x'}$ and $\mathbf{y'}$ satisfy the same equations above. Hence, $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left ( A\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{b}\right )=A\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\mathbf{x}(t)$$ And $$-GmM\frac{A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \| A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)\right \|^3}=-GmM\frac{A}{A^3}\left (\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t) \right \|^3} \right )$$ Now here is the *problem*; I need the RHS to have a factor of $A$ not $\frac{1}{A^2}$. In order to give the conclusion that the only difference by the change of variables is a factor of $A$ and since we assume $A$ is never the zero matrix, the physical laws are invariant under the Euclidean group.

Comment: Orthogonal transformations do not change the distances, i.e.
$${\left \| A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)\right \|} = {\left \| A\left(\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)\right)\right \|}={\left \| \mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)\right \|}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $A$ is a matrix, hence you can not write the line $$-GmM\frac{A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \| A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)\right \|^3}=-GmM\frac{A}{A^3}\left (\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t) \right \|^3} \right ),$$
it is quite false.

We know that  in general case $$\|Ax \|\le \|A\|\|x  \|.$$
Nevertheless, if $A\in O(3)$, then we always have $$\|Ax\|=\|x\|.$$
Therefore

$$-GmM\frac{A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \| A\mathbf{x}(t)-A\mathbf{y}(t)\right \|^3}=-GmM {A} \left (\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)}{\left \|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t) \right \|^3} \right ).$$